# Set span cursor to pointer in contenteditable div

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` tag in a `contenteditable` `div`. I want to set the `cursor` of `span` to `pointer`. This is my code:

```css
.myspan {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is a test text with <span class="myspan">pointer cursor</span> and editable</p>
</div>
```

This is works correctly in Firefox but in IE it doesn't work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Forget old IE. People need to upgrade with the times. Focus on Edge, Firefox and Chromium based browsers.

Comment: It doesn't work in Edge too. Is there any way to solve this problem in IE or Edge?

Comment: That's weird man... Cause according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_cursor_url&search=cursor%3A%20pointer%3B Edge supports it. Check your version.

Comment: When the div is contenteditable, Edge doesn't support cursor:pointer for span that is in div. My Edge version is 40.15063.674.0